# Why a specific html page does not show up in github pages?

Tags: github-pages

I found that some pages does not show up on the github pages site (`USER.github.io`), even they do exist in the corresponding repo (`https://github.com/USER/USER.github.io`). Why?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: github pages does not show a page other than the `index.html` when *there are no links to it.*